# Buddypress - Function won't work on front

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I got this function that lets the acitvity wall only displays posts. It works great on the activity page BUT when I go under reading options and diplay it as the front page the function wont work? It's displayed as static front page

Why?

Here is my code

```
<?php


function show_activity_update()
{
if(is_page('activity'))
{
echo '<style>ul#activity-stream li.groups , ul#activity-stream li.blogs , ul#activity-stream li.members , ul#activity-stream li.xprofile , ul#activity-stream li.friends {display:none;}</style>';
}
}
add_action('wp_head','show_activity_update');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `is_page` condition with `is_front_page`

try this:

```
<?php
function show_activity_update()
{
if(is_front_page())
{
echo '<style>ul#activity-stream li.groups , ul#activity-stream li.blogs , ul#activity-stream li.members , ul#activity-stream li.xprofile , ul#activity-stream li.friends {display:none;}</style>';
}
}
add_action('wp_head','show_activity_update');

?>
```